# Python package to convert the word "single" into the number 1

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to convert the words "single", "double", etc into numbers. All I could find so far is [word2number](https://pypi.org/project/word2number/) and [text2digits](https://pypi.org/project/text2digits/) but neither of them can do it. Anyone know of a package which can do this?

Comment: There are only about 10 words like that, and people rarely go beyond "sextuple", so just create a dictionary of them.

Comment: If other packages don't do the job you want, why don't you try making your own package or program to do this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Names_for_tuples_of_specific_lengths is the full list

Comment: Thanks everyone. I guess I'm not writing my own package because I'm lazy ;) Was hoping there would be something that solves this (and potential other numerical words) out of the box. I'll just write my own little dictionary to replace single and double for now.

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to close this sensibly, as-ever, **@Barmar** has the answer-

You can probably create a dictionary and simply try your words against it

```py
tuple_word_conversions = {
    "single": 1,
    "double": 2,
    "couple": 2,
    "triple": 3,
    ...
}
```

```py
>>> test_words
['double', 'scoop', 'ice', 'cream']
>>> for index, word in enumerate(test_words.copy()):
...     if (value := tuple_word_conversions.get(word)) is not None:
...         test_words[index] = value  # NOTE int without other changes
...
>>> test_words
[2, 'scoop', 'ice', 'cream']
```

Comment: I appreciate your input, @ti7 - there would be more words (like "half" and "tenth", etc) and if nobody has written a package that does this then that is the answer. I know that Spacy can identify such words, not sure if it can convert them.